# Is it possible host a custom google map on a website using an iframe or similar?

Tags: google-maps

Im trying to embed an google map onto a company website using the `<iframe>` method.

This works fine, but the resulting maps show a competitor who is geographically close to the company whos website i am working on.

We dont want someone to visit the website i am working on and see a competitors name.

Eg. please see attached screenshot. (FYI this is a random screenshot i have taken from google maps, i am not related with any of these companies) If i was working on "Company A"'s i wouldn't want to host a google map showing "Company B".

[image: example screenshot from google maps, showing company a and b in close proximity]

Accordingly is it possible to make a custom google map removing select certain pins that i dont want ?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom map and publish it instead of the standard Google Map iframe. That should allow you to highlight your client’s business, change the map pin, etc.

https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/

Answer (score 3):

I would start at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference where it states: *With style options you can customize the presentation of the standard Google map styles, changing the visual display of features like roads, parks, **businesses**, and other points of interest*

[untested] It looks like to hide businesses you would use

```
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using custom CSS and display none for other business and also making it more exact longitude and latitude will resolve this issue.

Most of style guides are here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference

Give it a try and you will resolve this easily.